# Is clearance of output caching clear all caching?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, output-caching

I have implemented output caching in my project on two action methods named "XYZ" & "ABC". Please note controller is different for both of the methods.

If I will clear the output caching of action "XYZ" on any event, will it clear caching of another action method too? Or Do I need to clear caching for second method as well? I am clearing caching using below code:

```
 var requestContext = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current),
    new System.Web.Routing.RouteData());

    var Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    var urlToRemove = Url.Action("XYZ", "controller");
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```

Please advice.

Comment: If you specifically clear one method out why would that clear another method?

Comment: Okay, that means I have to clear it all. Can you please tell me how output caching differ for different methods as object caching differ as per their key value?